# How to disable mouse scrolltabs ubuntu chrome

Tags: google-chrome

When I hover on tabs in chrome and scroll the mouse wheel, the tabs are changing focus. This feature is really annoying for me and i want to turn it off. Any ideas?

P.S. The way I usually close an opened tab is to hover the pointer over that tab and click the wheel (also known as middle button). This feature is kind of a convention and is available in many applications.

Comment: tabWheeler has the functions that you describe, and works for me under Ubuntu. Maybe you have it installed? It does not have any options (and is quite invisible), and works as long as it's installed and active. Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabwheeler/dhnmobobhmhfglpooaceblmodafejbfc?utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-et-na-us-oc-webstrhm&utm_medium=et

Comment: ok, I do it very often because I have a mouse with a more sensitive  wheel scroll (Logitech m705) and if i want to close a tab by pressing the scroll button when , it usually scrolls to another tab. :| 
@Esso: will try to find that extension

Comment: I have only one extension installed in chrome (adBlocker - blocks all ads.) I also installed tabwheeler thinking it will provide me a way to stop this behavior but it didn't

Comment: try to find this option here `chrome://flags/`

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If you did, please post it as an answer.

Comment: no, i didn't; the question has almost 1K viewers, but not a solution :(

Comment: Did you try the use of an extension to fix this?

Comment: I didn't, but i guess this cannot be achieved just from chrome settings. I should flag it as obsolete and remove it.

Comment: Head over to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=680499 and after logging in, click the star to vote for having an option added to chrome to turn on/off the switching of tabs when you use scrolling while cursor is over tab strip. Next, find as many people as you can to do the same. Don't add to the discussion there as that could defeat the purpose of starring the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is extension to chrome called Chrome Toolbox that does just that. Use it myself.

[Chrome Toolbox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/chrome%20toolbox)

Comment: Can you explain how you managed to see all those options (for me are just 3 or for and are not really useful) in the general tab

Comment: Holy-Cow I'm at work.... the non-linux version here has it. but my laptop (ubuntu) dosen't. when I get home I'll find a solution!!

Comment: Considering that Chrome Toolbox is no longer supported, this solution is fairly outdated.

Comment: It's too bad they didn't describe what the extension does at all.

Answer (score 0):

As of today this is built-in functionality within Chrome GTK/Linux only. Here is the key thread discussing the change: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1316

Windows users must use Chrome Toolbox (by Google) or an alternate solution. Unfortunately this extension and its control options aren't available on Chrome Linux's latest versions due to the drop for NPAPI support, as mentioned in the extension FAQ.

As a result, the only option I see is to pull down the source code for Chrome and modify the source, which I've done personally to make tweaks. It's not that hard to do and would be the route I would take. For this particular feature, I would simply undo / rollback the following change and recompile:

https://codereview.chromium.org/155053

If you click the "View" link under the column Side-by-side diffs and change the files to match the red version (old), that should essentially do the trick. Sorry this is technical in nature, but it would certainly solve the problem. Alternative suggestions welcome.